# Fixing layout of content within animated expanding div

Tags: html, css

On this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfhG2/),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
<div class="test">
    <h1>?</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph that offers more information about stuff, it can be accessed by hovering over the question mark. (Move your mouse away to shrink back.)</p>
</div>

<h1>Examples</h1>
<br />

<h3>My name is Shaun</h3>
<div class="test">
    <h1>?</h1>
    <p>People with this name tend to be passionate, compassionate, intuitive, romantic, and to have magnetic personalities. They are usually humanitarian, broadminded and generous, and tend to follow professions where they can serve humanity. Because they are so affectionate and giving, they may be imposed on. They are romantic and easily fall in love, but may be easily hurt and are sometimes quick-tempered.</p>
</div>
<h3>I am on a see food diet</h3>
<div class="test">
    <h1>?</h1>
    <p>when I see food, I want to eat it.</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

there are 2 problems in which I would like to address:

1. Hover over the question marks, you can see that as the div expands the text within it constantly re formats itself to fit inside the div. What I want to happen instead is the text is already at the correct size based off of what the DIV will be when it is fully expanded.
2. How can I dynamically choose the size of the DIV so that it's maximum expanded size is the size of the text contained within it I tried 100%, but that just makes it the size of the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Getting it so that the text doesn't reposition as the container expands requires that you set the width of the paragraph element equal to the width of the expanded box:

```
.test:hover, .test p {
    width: 750px;
}
```

Also, you had the `p` element set to `display: inline;` which had to be changed to `display: block;` (although `inline-block` would also work) since you can't explicitly set the width on `inline` elements.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UfhG2/6/

2) This is a little trickier. Without scripting, you can't get an element to shrink to the size of it's content without using `auto` for either `height` or `width`, and as far as I'm aware you can't easily transition from a specified `height` or `width` to `auto`, but there are some suggestions here:

http://n12v.com/css-transition-to-from-auto/

Or, as an easy compromise, you can set:

```
.test:hover {
    height: auto;
}
```

So that, the height won't transition, but you'll still get a reasonably sized box, and the width will still expand nicely.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UfhG2/8/

3) Also, you might want to think about using [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) instead of repeating `<h1>?</h1>`:

```
.test:before {
    content:'?';
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.test:hover:before {
    display: none;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UfhG2/7/

Comment: Thanks! +1 for psuedo elements